# PHP Math Percentage

Tags: php, math

Hi I've been rattling my brain to solve this.

imagine 100%

we have 2 numbers

6788.08 & 11629.60

how do I get the percentage of each number.

for example I think

100%

10 & 100

10% & 90%

is the example correct? I haven't a clue on how to get the 2 ratios in %

Comment: You need to provide another variable. `6788.08` is `67.8%` of `10,000`, but is also `6.78%` of `100,000`. What is the total that you are trying to determine what `6788.08` and `11629.60` are a percentage of?

Comment: the highest number I think is 100% the lowest number is % of the highest?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take two numbers `$number1` and `$number2`, then the total of the two numbers, `$sum`, is `$number1 + $number2`.

Now, getting the percentage of each is trivial:

```
$sum = $number1 + $number2;
$percentage1 = $number1 / $sum;
$percentage2 = $number2 / $sum;
```

Comment: thankyou, u made it look so easy, and it seems it was, thankyou :)

Answer (score 0):

Add both numbers:

```
$sum = 6788.08 + 11629.60;
```

Then divide each number by that sum to get the proportion of each:

```
$percentage_number1 = 6788.08 / $sum;
```

So you get a ratio. Multiply that ratio by 100, and you can print it out as `%`.

Answer (score 0):

While I'm not sure about your example, something like this should work:

```
$number = 6788.08;
$number2 = 11629.60;
$summedamt = $number+$number2;

$avg1 = $number/$summedamt;
$avg2 = $number2/$summedamt;
```

Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to normalize the values. If you have `x` and `y` then with two proportions you get your answer. If you assume that `1.0f == 100%` this become trivial:

```
xperc = x / (x + y)
yperc = y / (x + y)
```

Of course if you want to have a printable result you will have to multiply by 100 and truncate decimals.

Answer (score 0):

What we learned in high school math is: **is** over **of** equals percent over 100.

6788.08 + 11629.60 = 18417.68

6788.08 **is** what percent **of** 18417.68?

6788.08 (is) / 18417.68 (of) = % / 100

6788.08 / 18417.68 = 0.369 = % / 100

0.369 * 100 = 36.9%

Do the same with the other number.